# Recreate a custom cell when user swipes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm developping an app using iOS5 and Xcode 4.3.3.

I have a **UserTableViewController** which is a **TableViewController** created by using **CustomCell** which is a subclass of **UITableViewCell**. So far, Everything is working just fine.

I also implemented these two methods to get user swipes. For now, i'm able to show delete button when user swipes .

```c
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSDictionary *dictionaryWithUrl = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Urls" ofType:@"plist"]];
        NSString *baseUrl = [dictionaryWithUrl objectForKey:@"urlWithNews"];
        baseUrl = [baseUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"/delete?newsId=%d",[[[self.arrayWithUserNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"newsId" ]intValue]];
        NSURLRequest *requestToDeleteNews = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]];
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestToDeleteNews returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        [self.arrayWithUserNews  removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] ;
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }   
}
```

Well,what i want to do is recreate a custom cell,after swiping to have another functionalities. Because,for the app i'm developping, it's not enough to delete a cell. User can edit a table cell as well. Here is an example,what i do want to create . This's Twitter iOS Application example.They did what exactly i needed.  
**Initial cell**

[image]

**After user swipe**

[image]

Attention,just to be clear,they appear exactly the same location.

Is there anybody who can give me the right path to accomplish this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this project](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/SideSwipeTableView)

It does exactly what u want

Answer (score 0):

The cell isn't getting deleted, it's just showing another view on top of itself. You need to create a custom cell, subclass it, and then be able to recognize a sideways gesture. When you detect the gesture, change the view displayed by the cell.

Comment: How can i know which cell is swiped on to switch its view to another one ?

Comment: You'll do it in the cell subclass, not in the table delegate methods

Comment: Ok,i think i got it . Thanks a bunch